# Split string with delimiter as array vba?

Tags: vba

I have a specific document with 5 lines of text. lines are separated by delimiter.
I am reading whole document as string and looking forward to split it using delimiter in VBA.

Any help please!!!!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+split  Please at least *try* Googling before asking this type of question. It's pretty easy to discover basic language features.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
Sub SplitTest() 
    Dim splitTarget As Variant 
    Dim splitString as string
    splitString = "test1,test2,test3"

    splitTarget = Split(splitString, ",") 
End Sub
```