# reading line by line. how to separate strings?

Tags: vba

I searched solution for my  problem but i could not complete  missing parts of the writing/reading into file stuff.

how can i call each string which separated by comma as a variable from text file?

example textfile: 1,4,5,123,5,2,24,5

my code

```
Dim y, z,x

Set y = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set z = y.OpenTextFile("C:\input.txt",1)

x= z.readline 

f.Close
```

Comment: My awesome Google-fu reveals an MSDN article devoted to reading text files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: that is not valid VB.NET code

Comment: This question is unclear because it's tagged `vb.net` but doesn't contain `vb.net` code.

Comment: yup, looks like VBA or VBScript

Comment: [It's definitely VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string with delimiter as array vba?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358652/split-string-with-delimiter-as-array-vba)

Answer (score 0):

The TextStream object returned by a call to FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile() does not provide a facility to read comma separated values. You have to provide the parsing your self. You can read the line and then use the Split() function to pull each value into an array and then populate the variable or use the array directly as MyValues({index); It has been a long time since VBA so it may not work correctly but the principal should still apply

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim fso, MyFile, FileName, TextLine, Values

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

' Read from the file and display the results.
Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine

    Values = Split(TextLine, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(Values)
       Debug.Print Values(i)
    Next i
Loop
MyFile.Close
```